# undefined array key and don't know where that key comes from

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm following this one,
https://www.androidhire.com/insert-data-from-app-to-mysql-android/

and there's an error in Step 'Upload the php script on your server',
'code for get_data.php file'

```
<?php

include 'DatabaseConfig.php' ;
 
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);
 
 
     $room = $_POST['room'];
     $time = $_POST['time'];


 $Sql_Query = "insert into GetDataTable (room,time) values ('$room','$time')";
 
 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){
 
 echo 'Data Submit Successfully';
 
 }
 else{
 
 echo 'Try Again';
 
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

this is my code and my database table is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AqiT.png)

and error message is
**Warning: Undefined array key "room" in C:\xampp\htdocs\get_data.php on line 8**

so I tried

```
if(isset($_POST['room']){
        $room = $_POST['room'];
    }
```

but this gave me **Warning: Undefined variable**

Comment: Pls change your query to parameterized prepared statement to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `if()` around the whole block of code that uses `$room`:

```
<?php

include 'DatabaseConfig.php' ;
 
$con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);
 
if ( isset( $_POST['room'] ) ) {
   $room = $_POST['room'];
   $time = $_POST['time'];

   $Sql_Query = "insert into GetDataTable (room,time) values ('$room','$time')";
 
   if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){
       echo 'Data Submit Successfully';
   } else{
       echo 'Try Again';
   }
   mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```